# Random line artifacts on mesh when moved too far from global 0, 0, 0

Tags: mesh, coordinates

I'm attempting to render a mesh in 2.8. However, random lines appear on its surface when positioned too far from the global `0, 0, 0` coordinates. I've cut out a small portion of mesh with one such line as an example, and provided a .blend file with the bare minimum, in order to narrow down the possible causes:

[image: Example mesh]

[image]

That darker line going horizontally across the mesh is one of several such lines riddling my mesh. Moving the mesh up about as far as `0, 0, 150` is fine, but beyond that, the lines appear more pronounced, and there seem to be more of them that appear. Since distance from `0, 0, 0` seems to be the primary factor, I thought I'd try changing the scene's unit scale from 1 to 0.1 or 0.01, but this made no difference.

I've also included my material node setup below:

[image: Node setup]

I've noticed the lines only appear when using `Principled BSDF`. I thought I'd try using `Diffuse BSDF` in its place, but it also had the same issue. What was odd was when I replaced it with `Emission`, the lines disappeared. Same thing happened when attaching `ColorRamp` directly to `Material Output`. No lines.

So from what I'm getting with all of this, the problem lies with distance from `0, 0, 0`. Since changing unit scale makes no difference, I suspect the problem is further narrowed down to the ratio, or relationship between coordinates, rather than absolute values. And somehow, the nodes, possibly the diffuse feature, may have an influence. But above all, what this tells me is that I have absolutely no idea how to actually fix the problem.

Anybody have an idea what I should do?

Comment: If you move it closer to the origin it works properly. You placed that object which is a couple cm long, 500 m (!) from the origin.

Comment: No idea how I set my origin that far away, but that's definitely fixed it. I never would have thought to check the origin, even if I remembered setting it like that. I'm curious, though. How does the origin affect this? What's the relationship between it and...I'm guessing the material node?

Comment: Okay, I played around with this some more, and the issue is still there. I thought it was solved after I moved the mesh down to 0, 0, 0, but when I moved it back up to 0, 0, 500 and set the origin to centre of volume, the issue remained. Will edit post with this new information.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear I didn't mean the object's origin, I meant the origin of the coordinate system.

Comment: The coordinate system origin being 0, 0, 0, correct? So does that mean there's no possible solution to this? How would I work with large scenes? Thought I could change the scene unit scale from 1 to 0.1, but it made no difference.

Comment: Thanks for your time, anyway.

Comment: Alright found the issue. It's a reason I suspected but wasn't sure about. You are actually having a numerical precision problem with floating point numbers.

Comment: The issue on the bug tracker where this is discussed https://developer.blender.org/T43835

Comment: Looks like a viable workaround would be to parent everything to an empty and move that around to keep the active camera close to 0, 0, 0. I can live with that. Will give it a try and see if it works.